# File Not Found in Delphi (FMX)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to load a bunch of lines from a text file located in same directory as the .dproj and Delphi can't find the file I'm trying to read from.
the code is as follows:

```
    procedure TFoPrincipale.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var monFich : TextFile;
    Sligne : string;
begin
try
AssignFile(monFich, 'docText.txt');
Reset(monFich); 
except
      showmessage('Le fichier est introuvable');
      exit;
end;

  while not Eof (monFich) do
  begin
    Readln(monFich, Sligne);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Sligne);
  end;

CloseFile(monFich);

end;
```

[image: The text file]

Comment: You are not providing a path to the file and I see a Win32 subfolder there. Your executable is most probably in that subfolder and I suspect its working directory will be that one. Try it out first with specifying a complete path in the filename

Comment: yes it's working when I move it over to Win32\Debug
I'll try specifying the complete path to it and give you feedback.
Thanks mate

Comment: Both methods are working.

Comment: Have a look at the concept of "Working/Current directory" and also how to dynamically get the path you require

Comment: Never use relative paths.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Unless you are writing a conosle app

Answer (score 6):

If you are using default project options then your application executable isn't compiled into the project directory but instead into the `Win32\Debug` or `Win32\Release` subfolder of your project folder.

So you should take into account the relative path to your file. In your case, the desired file is in second parent folder of the folder in which your executable resides.

I recommend you first get the path location of your executable file using `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`.

Then you can make use of [`TDirectory.GetParent()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetParent) in order to move up the directory chain until you reach the desired directory.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very very insightful comment.